# Optimize the query for better performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, query-performance

So I have this function.

Let say I have **millions** of posts.

How can I optimize this function?

```
def fun
  Post.all.each do |post|
    if post.user.present?
       post.active = true
    else
       post.active = false
    end
    post.save
  end
end
```

Like do this in fewer line with better performance because this is not a very good approach.

Comment: You can do it in two queries: 1) `Post.where(user_id: nil).update_all active: false` 2) `Post.where('user_id IS NOT NULL').update_all active: true`. But it won't fire callbacks

Comment: `Post.all` will build objects for every record what leads to big memory consumption as well

Comment: Thanks that's what i need

Comment: @jeffdill2 I don't know. I guess the answer has to be more comprehensive. And I think there is a way to do it with one request using something like sql `case` statement

Comment: By the way @k00ka gave the best option

Comment: @jeffdill2 no problem, I will consider it in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another option that does it in two queries without any raw SQL (just plain ol' Rails):

```
Post.where(user_id: nil).update_all(active: false)
Post.where.not(user_id: nil).update_all(active: true)
```

And, believe it or not, this actually runs faster in the database than doing it in one query that's using an expression – `active = (user_id IS NOT NULL)` – to populate `active`.

Here are the speed results from testing on a table with only 20,000 records:

```
# Single (expression-based) query
<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fd251a52780 @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @label="", @real=2.3656239999982063, @stime=0.0, @total=0.009999999999999787, @utime=0.009999999999999787>

# Two (purely column-based) queries
<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fd2518c36d0 @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @label="", @real=2.309347999995225, @stime=0.0, @total=0.0, @utime=0.0>
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick - and it's FAST...

```
Post.update_all("active = (user_id IS NOT NULL)")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Post.connection.execute \
  "UPDATE posts SET active = TRUE WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL"
```

---

The proper approach would be to remove `active` field from the database and implement the ruby getter in `Post` class:

```
def active
  user.present?
end
```

Comment: @ndn Nah. The best approach in any case would be to remove `active` field from the database and implement `def active; user.present?; end`.

Comment: You don't know that. An `active` post might mean something completely different and it's just that OP wants to populate it with these values initially.

Comment: You don't have to use plain SQL. It's not Rails way. ActiveRecord allows to do it as well

Comment: @user3309314 Rails sucks, I never use Rails way if possible.

Comment: @mudasobwa as you wish

Comment: @ndn I know that if you need to populate any field with some other field’s values then something went wrong with the design :)

Comment: @mudasobwa, why so? Imagine that OP wants to implement a new feature that allows users to soft delete their posts. In order to do that, users can set the post as active/inactive. The question is what to do with the existing data. It is perfectly sensible to create a one time rake task to mark posts without a user as inactive and ones with - as active.

Comment: @ndn Eh? “posts without a user”? Even if this is legit (also I doubt it might be,) they should not be soft-deleted all of a sudden.

Comment: I agree that the fact that users are hard deleted if posts are soft deleted is a bit of a wtf. But even then, if floating posts should be hidden all of the sudden can be a business decision. Also this was just one interpretation of `active`, it might mean something completely different.

Comment: This answer is only setting `active` when a user isn't present. It's not accounting for setting `active` to false when a user _is_ present.